# "rotation" does not fill Layout

Tags: android, xamarin, rotation, signaturepad

I have this `Layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutSign"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="1000dp"
    android:minHeight="1000dp"
    android:padding="2dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout8"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:id="@+id/layoutSignaturePad"
            android:background="#FF0055"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            android:padding="10dp">
            <SignaturePad.SignaturePadView
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/signaturePad" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout14"
            android:weightSum="100"
            android:background="#00FFFF">
            <TextView
                android:text="Text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/textSignInfoTemp"
                android:layout_weight="0" />
            <Button
                android:text="Button"
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:rotation="90"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="50" />
            <Button
                android:text="Button"
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:rotation="90"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="50" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It creates this `View`:

[image]

Now I would like to rotate the [Signature Pad](https://components.xamarin.com/view/signature-pad) by setting the rotation to 90 but it causes this `View` where the `Width` and `Height` are not changed on the SignaturePad (The gray line on the first picture is not visible on the second image).

[image]

I have tried to change the rotation on the `Layout`, the `SignaturePad` and both without getting the expected result.

All screens on my application is in Portrait mode and this `View` is being popped in a `DialogFragment` and I would like to give the illusion of it being in `Landscape` mode without changing the `Orientation` in the `Activity` or creating a new `Activity` just for this screen.

Question: How can I rotate the `SignaturePad` and have it fill its parent `Layout`?

Comment: Better way to use percent layout instead of linear layout it will definitely solve your pro.blem.

Comment: you should swipe height and width of Signature pad After Rotation with older values by passing LayoutParmas